# How to run a Regex expression in an uploaded log file using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, file-upload, logfile

I'm building a web-based log parser system using Ruby on Rails. I already finished the function for uploading log files and I also already have the Regex Expression for capturing the information that I need from each log file entry. As you know, a log file may contain thousands of log file entries and they usually follow the same pattern.

For instance:

```
Processing NameofController#index (for 999.999.999.999 at 2019-01-24 00:12:00) [GET]
  Session ID: aaaaaabbbbbbcccccc11112222333
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"sample_invoices", "action"=>"index", 
"before"=>"2019-01-24T12:00:00Z", "soap_id"=>"0001", 
"s"=>"sample", "format"=>"xml"}
Sample chain halted as [:example] rendered_or_redirected.
Completed in 0.00022 (4588 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00010 (44%) | DB: 0.00000 (0%) | 401 Unauthorized [http://www.iwantsoaps.com/pages/sample.xml?s=sample&soap_id=0001&before=2019-01-24T12:00:00Z]
```

Can someone recommend a way for me to read each log file using regex after they have been uploaded? I simply don't know where to start. I need to store the captured values inside a database as well.

Comment: The rails log is not similar to apache logs in which all lines have the same pattern.

Comment: The log files that are to be uploaded all come from one application. After studying them I noticed that all of them follow the same pattern as above so it is not an issue :)